# Use of uninitialised value in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 29

Tags: regex, perl, loops

I wrote a Perl script that basically does this: It opens 2 text files that are very similar.
Actually one is the older version of the other. The older version has footnotes and marginal notes that I want to transfer to the newer version of the text.

To do so I make a regex-search for the footnote or marginal note and I try to get the word before the note to use it as a search word, so that I can find the correct position for the notes the new version of the text. Finding a searchword, that I can use is not in every case possible.

So in case my search word search fails, I still need to transfer the note to the newer file (adding an `errortoken = &xQUADER;`).

The following is more or less only the problem part of the script. It fails with the warning message in the title of this question at line 29 (marked: `FEHLERzeile`).

```
LABEL:
while ($oldscovers =~ /<(f|m)n id="[bkvl0-9]+"\/>/) {

    $oldscovers =~ s/( [a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜßï<>()"\-]+[.:,;!?]["]|
[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜßï<>()"\-]+  [".:,;!?]| [a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜßï<>()"\-]+|
[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜßï<>(),"\-]+)(<(f|m)n( id="[bkvl0-9]+"\/>))/$1/;

    my $searchword = $1;
    my $transfn    = $2;

    #
    unless (defined $searchword) {
        $oldscovers =~ s/(<(f|m)n( id="[bkvl0-9]+"\/>))//;
        my $transfnfailsearch = $&;

        #
        $newelbchap =~ s/(<verse num="${oldscoversnr}">[^ÿ]+<\/verse>)/$1/;
        my $newelbvers = $1;
        $newelbvers =~ s/<verse num="${oldscoversnr}">\n//;
        my $cuttag = $&;

        #
        $newelbvers =~ s/<s>/<s>\&xQUADER\;${transfnfailsearch}/;

        #
        $newelbvers =~ s/(.+)/${cuttag}$1/;    # hier wird $cuttag wieder eingefügt
        $newelbchap =~ s/<verse num="${oldscoversnr}">[^ÿ]+<\/verse>/${newelbvers}/;

        #
        next LABEL;
    }

    #
    #

    $newelbchap =~ s/(<verse num="${oldscoversnr}">[^ÿ]+<\/verse>)/$1/;
    my $newelbvers = $1;

    $newelbvers =~ s/<verse num="${oldscoversnr}">\n//;
    my $cuttag = $&;

    if ($newelbvers =~ /${searchword}([ .?!:;,])/) {
        $newelbvers =~ s/(${searchword})([ .?!:;,])/${searchword}${transfn}$2/; ## FEHLERzeile
    }
    elsif ($newelbvers =~ /${searchword}/) {
        $newelbvers =~ s/${searchword}/${searchword}${transfn}/;
    }
    else {
        $newelbvers =~ s/<s>/<s>\&QUADER\;${transfn}/;
    }

    $newelbvers =~ s/(.+)/${cuttag}$1/;  # hier wird $cuttag wieder eingefügt
    $newelbchap =~ s/<verse num="${oldscoversnr}">[^ÿ]+<\/verse>/${newelbvers}/;
}
```

I think I get this message because the script is not restarting at `LABEL`, called at the end of the `unless` block.

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`! And some indentation wouldn't hurt.

Comment: ...then once you have no errors or warnings, run it through a debugger.

Comment: I've had to indent your Perl code and add a lot of whitespace so that I could read it. You can't possibly be sure of your block nesting with no layout at all. Once of the problems is likely to be your three-line substitution regex pattern. The newlines are part of the pattern, and the regex engine won't find a match unless it finds them in the object string.

Comment: I can't immediately see how `$transfn` can be undefined unless `$searchword` is also undefined, but you should `use Data::Dumper` and `print Dumper $searchword, $transfn` as soon as they are assigned, and again immediately before line 29 to see what values you are getting.

Comment: @Borodin Thank you for looking at the code. Sorry this is the first time I use this website and I had problems getting the code into the system. So please forgive, I put in the newlines in the search regex because it broke awful on screen. I thought I had to put only 4 spaces before each line, so I lost all indentation.

Comment: It is right, I will either get $transfn AND $searchword undef OR defined. Therefore I put in the unless-Block to solve the problem with the undefined Variables that I could get through non-matching searches. Is the unless-Block correctly coded? At the beginning and at the end?

Comment: Normaly the "next LABEL" command should force the script to proceed with the next loop of the first while block, which it does not seem to do. Or it does not even start the unless block!?

Comment: To add preformatted code to your question, copy it from your source and paste it in. Then highlight the block of code and hit Ctrl-K and it will indent the whole block by four spaces for you. I suggest you replace my edit now with your real code inserted in that way.

Comment: If the error is occurring on the marked line, then the `unless` block hasn't been entered because `$searchword` is *defined*. As I said, I can't see how that can be defined without `$transfn` also being defined, so you should trace the values of those variables as I described.

Comment: Let your script tell you itself what it's doing. Put some debugging output in it. Before the `unless`, `print STDERR "before unless\n";` at the top of the block, `print STDERR "inside unless\n";`, before the `next LABEL`, `print STDERR "About to do next\n";`, after the block, `print STDERR "After unless\n";`and so on. Add some `Data::Dumper`'ing of the relevant variables at each point. Work backwards in the stderr stream from the "undefined value" warning to the point where it originated.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your help. I worked in the STDERR and the Dumper stuff. Then I run the Script again and I found out, that $transfn is indeed undef BUT $searchword is not. It holds an "m", which I do not understand. It should also be undef, when the search fails.

Comment: While thinking about this, I come to the conclusion, that if I use $transfn instead of $searchword in the unless block, the script should work. And it does!!! Still it is not satifying to not know why $searchword still holds an "m". It was hard to find the place in the error output, because the data ran like crasy over the screen and the console in windows seems to only hold like a few hundred lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the latest comments, I understand what went wrong. This line:

```
while ($oldscovers =~ /<(f|m)n id="[bkvl0-9]+"\/>/) {
```

executes a regular expression with a single set of capturing parentheses. When it succeeds, `$1` is set to the `f` or `m` that was matched, `$2`, `$3`, `$4`, etc. are set to `undef`, and the loop body is entered.

The first thing in the loop body is the big `s///` which contains 2 sets of capturing parentheses. When it succeeds, it sets `$1` and `$2` to the captured strings and sets `$3`, `$4`, etc. to `undef`.

When the big `s///` fails to match, it leaves all of those capture variables as they were before. The `f` or `m` is still in `$1` and the `undef` is still in `$2`. Since you didn't test for success or failure of the big `s///` the `f` or `m` from `$1` goes into `$searchword` and the `undef` from `$2` goes into `$transfn`.

What you should do to fix this is think of how you want the script to behave when the big `s///` doesn't find a match, and write the code to do that if the `s///` yields a false value.

For example you might choose one of these:

```
$oldscovers =~ s/.../.../ or next;
$oldscovers =~ s/.../.../ or last;
$oldscovers =~ s/.../.../ or die "something bad happened with this string: $oldscovers";
```

or even this:

```
my $searchword;
my $transfn;
if($oldscovers =~ s/.../.../) {
  $searchword = $1;
  $transfn = $2;
}
```

which would make sure that `$searchword` and `$transfn` are undef if there was no match. And here's another way of doing that:

```
my ($searchword, $transfn) = $oldscovers =~ s/.../.../ ? ($1,$2) : ();
```

Comment: OK, I understand! To now known what has happend is very helpful to avoid further problems. THANK YOU very much!!